# Laravel filters in route or controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Is there a best practice for where to put the filters? I want to put filter on each action for a resource (e.g: user), which can look overwhelming if I put them all in `routes.php`, but most people do it. If I apply the filters in the controllers, I want to do that for everything else too so other people always know where to look.

How do you organize your filters?

Comment: If you're gonna have a lot of them, I'd recommend putting it on a `FilterServiceProvider`.

Comment: please read this [link](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#controller-filters)

Comment: @RajibGhosh I am aware of controller filters. I just want to know the best practice for organizing them.

Comment: @Raphael_ i think you can use any one ...i think it's does not meter which one is best.but The route/filter would be hit first, before the controller.so you have to decide which one is you choice

Comment: This depends solely on your preferences. I like to put the filters in my route files so the controllers don't need to know anything about them. Also remember to choose one and **stick** to it, otherwise you have to go back and forth to know what's going on

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter where you put your filters (either in routes or controllers). But basically, it would be easy and understandable if you will rule your **routes**.